# How to make Node cluster skip a busy worker process?

Tags: node.js, node-cluster

I'm trying to write in Node (currently using version 18) a web server where one of the routes can be computation heavy so it will run for a long time and max out its CPU core with 100%.
To keep every other request responsive I thought that a Node cluster would be a great fit.

Extremely simplifying the code I ended up with:

```
import cluster from 'cluster';
import { createServer } from 'http';

const startUpTime = Date.now();

function requestListener(request, response) {
  console.log(`[${(Date.now()-startUpTime)/1000}] pid ${process.pid} is serving URL ${request.url}`);
  response.writeHead(200);
  if (request.url === '/slow') {
    for (let cnt = 0; cnt < 100; cnt++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++ ) { /* just wait */ }
      response.write(`${cnt}.`);
    }
  }
  response.end(`... pid ${process.pid} done...\n`);
  console.log(`[${(Date.now()-startUpTime)/1000}] pid ${process.pid} finished serving URL ${request.url}`);
}

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let worker = cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  // the worker:
  const server = createServer(requestListener);
  server.listen(8000, 'localhost', () => {
    console.info(`Server ${process.pid} is running`);
  });
}
```

But this code doesn't run as expected. Although my system has 12 cores and is basically idle this is happening:

1. Running in terminal #1 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` - immediate result as expected
2. Running in terminal #1 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` - immediate result as expected
3. Running in terminal #2 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/slow` - immediate headers, slowly building up response text `0.1.2.3` and 100% CPU load, as expected
4. Running in terminal #1 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` - immediate result as expected
5. Running in terminal #1 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` - immediate result as expected
6. Running in terminal #1 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` - immediate result as expected
7. Running in terminal #1 `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/test` - **no immediate result as is is blocked till request 3. is finished**

The console output shows exactly the problem:

```
Server 78797 is running
Server 78799 is running
Server 78798 is running
Server 78800 is running
[3.028] pid 78797 is serving URL /test
[3.029] pid 78797 finished serving URL /test
[3.515] pid 78799 is serving URL /test
[3.52] pid 78799 finished serving URL /test
[5.963] pid 78798 is serving URL /slow
[7.27] pid 78800 is serving URL /test
[7.272] pid 78800 finished serving URL /test
[7.976] pid 78797 is serving URL /test
[7.976] pid 78797 finished serving URL /test
[8.568] pid 78799 is serving URL /test
[8.569] pid 78799 finished serving URL /test
[32.492] pid 78798 finished serving URL /slow
[32.495] pid 78798 is serving URL /test
[32.495] pid 78798 finished serving URL /test
```

So why is the request at step 7. sent to the busy worker (pid 78798) although three other processes are idle and getting bored?

The manual promised me to do it a bit more intelligent than dumb round robin (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works):

> The cluster module supports two methods of distributing incoming
> connections.
>
> The first one (and the default one on all platforms except Windows) is
> the round-robin approach, where the primary process listens on a port,
> accepts new connections and distributes them across the workers in a
> round-robin fashion, **with some built-in smarts to avoid overloading a
> worker process**.

How can I change that behavior, so that all requests are answered immediately, even when one of the processes of my cluster pool is completely busy?

Comment: I think what you want is a jobQueue and a set of workerThreads and you send a workerThread an incoming job only when it's finished with the previous one.  Whenever a worker finishes, you check the queue and send the worker the next job in the queue.  That way, you never send a worker a job when it's already busy.  This workerQueue scheme handles things better when you have some requests that take a really long time and many other requests that do not.

Comment: FYI, the clustering load balancing algorithm provides minimal control via [cluster.schedulingPolicy](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy) and likely doesn't offer you the control you ask for.

Comment: Adding `cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_NONE;` to the code made it run as expected (OS I'm using is Linux). So I really wonder whether it's a bug in the round-robin code as sending tasks to a busy cluster never makes sense IMHO.  

I see your point about using a jobQueue as it would work in this (extremely simplified) use case as expected. But instead doing that myself I thought that the `cluster` would do exactly that for me when it's listening on the network port. So it's probably just me misunderstanding the documentation.